Grafana/PromQL: midnight to midnight change in counter
Let's say I have a posts_total counter. It increases every day, and it has various labels, like posts_total{status='active'} and posts_total{status='deleted'}.
delta(posts_total{status=~"active|deleted"}[1d]) shows me a rolling graph of the change in each day.

However this is not very useful, because it's a rolling change, and if I zoom in it loses any meaning because it shows differing rates at every hour.
How can I get a graph that shows me the change every day from midnight to midnight, instead of a rolling delta? I want a bar graph that I can use to tell exactly how much of an increase there was 2 days ago, or 3 months ago, at a specific day.

delta() vs. counter-specific functions - rate() / irate() / increase()
According to the doc, delta() is supposed to be used with Gauges, not with Counters. There are 3 dedicated functions to use with Counters that handles counters resets and does extrapolation: rate(), irate() and increase(). Most likely you need the later - increase(). This is a great article on the topic.
Graph query
To show the graph, Grafana executes something like 'range query' to request a matrix of query results for the specified time period.
So your query increase(posts_total{status=~"active|deleted"}[1d]) is executed multiple times to draw the graph. How many times is it executed? It depends on the selected time period parameters ("start" and "end") and the "step" parameter.
F.e. if the start=12-00, end=13-00 and step=20m - you should have something like 3 values on the graph, all of them showing the 1 day counter increase, that is specified by the range parameter in the query (1d).
So it's not really a "rolling delta", but the requested 1-day delta with (probably) 1-hour frequency.
It makes sense to keep range > step, because otherwise the result will miss some samples (just imagine a 1-hour counter increase executed each day - the data for 23 hours is skipped).
